# Prove the generalization of Taylor's formula.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let f, g, and h be polynomials over a subfield of the complex numbers, with deg f$\leq$n. Then 
$$
f(g)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}f^{(k)}(h)(g-h)^k.
$$

How can I solve it by using the prime factorization?